# Create video from PNGs with FFMPEG and variable per image timestamps

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, screenshot, frame-rate, vsync

I'm trying to take a pile of screenshot PNGs, and the timestamp of each screenshot, and create a video with `ffmpeg` that recreates the timing of the screenshots.

According to the `ffmpeg` help, `-vsync 0` seems to be what I need,

> -vsync parameter
>
> 0, passthrough Each frame is passed with its timestamp from the
> demuxer to the muxer.

Does anyone know how to pass this timestamp information into `ffmpeg`? Presently each screenshot has the recording time in milliseconds as the filename.

The below example doesn't accept any timing information that I can tell, so I'm looking for the proper format to pipe to the command.

`ffmpeg -vsync 0 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v libx264 output.mp4`

Comment: ffmpeg can use the modified file time to set timestamps but not the filename,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script: get time from filename, minus previous filetime = duration of temp video, then concat videos

```
#!/bin/bash
LST=($(ls -1tr Screenshot*.png))
TOT=${#LST[*]}
f="${LST[0]}"
#Screenshot_20201115_135335.png
FNM="${f%.*}"
SEC="${FNM:24:2}"
MIN="${FNM:22:2}"
HOU="${FNM:20:2}"
echo $f $HOU $MIN $SEC
BEG=$(echo "$HOU * 3600 + $MIN * 60 + $SEC" | bc -l)
echo $f $BEG
INP=("-i" "$f")
OUT="${f%.*}.mkv"
TXT=list.txt
echo "#png to mkv" > $TXT

for (( i=1; i<=$(( $TOT -1 )); i++ )); do
  f="${LST[$i]}"
  FNM="${f%.*}"
  SEC="${FNM:24:2}"
  MIN="${FNM:22:2}"
  HOU="${FNM:20:2}"
  TIM=$(echo "$HOU * 3600 + $MIN * 60 + $SEC" | bc -l)
  DUR=$(echo "$TIM - $BEG" | bc -l)
  echo $f $TIM $DUR
  ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loop 1 "${INP[@]}" -t $DUR "/tmp/${OUT}"
  echo "file '/tmp/${OUT}'" >> $TXT
  BEG=$TIM
  INP=("-i" "$f")
  OUT="${f%.*}.mkv"
done

ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loop 1 "${INP[@]}" -t 5 "/tmp/${OUT}"
echo "file '/tmp/${OUT}'" >> $TXT

cat "$TXT"
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -safe 0 -i "$TXT" -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 20 -y /tmp/output.mkv
ffplay /tmp/output.mkv
```